# Is there an equivalent to knex.pluck() that will return values for multiple columns?

Tags: knex.js

In [How to return a plain value from a Knex / Postgresql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833460/how-to-return-a-plain-value-from-a-knex-postgresql-query), I asked about getting just the column values from a Knex query, without a JSON object containing the column name. I was advised to use `pluck(fieldName)`.

That works fine if I return a single column in my query. How can I return multiple columns in similar format? I'm looking for something like `pluck([fieldName1, fieldname2])` or  `pluck(fieldName1, fieldname2)` and for each row, returning `["value1", "value2"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets first go over how does [knex.js](https://knexjs.org) currently implement [pluck](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-pluck) and then see if we can figure out a working solution which would fit to your needs.

So essentially what `pluck` does is that it modifies the query to include pluck column in the select statement and then it processes the response using [lodash.map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) to only return an array of pluck field values (instead of Array of result objects). Meaning it is internally running something like `lodash.map(resultsArray, pluckColumnName);` on the result of the query.

So using tiny code examples this means that:

Regular query:

1. `knex('product').limit(10); // regular query`
2. `` SELECT * FROM `product` LIMIT 10 // translates into wildcard select from the table ``
3. `[{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {...}] // result is Array of Objects with all columns from the table`

Regular query with pluck:

1. `knex('product').limit(10).pluck('id'); // query with pluck`
2. `` SELECT id FROM `product` LIMIT 10 // translates into specific column select ``
3. `loadsh.map(results, 'id') // knex internally runs loadsh.map on the results`
4. `[1, 2, 3, ...] // we get array of pluck column values back`

If you are looking to pluck multiple columns you just need to change the result map function to instead of returning only a single value to return an array of multiple values. This can be done in multiple ways:

**Solution #1:**

Easiest way doing this is to manually include the pluck columns in the query and then running regular [Array Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the results. Code would look something like this:

```js
// construct the query, make sure the fields you want to get values for are present
// it's best to include them in the .select statement because you really don't care for other fields
const query = knex('product').select('id', 'name').limit(10);

return query
  .then(results => {
    return results.map(result => [result.id, result.name]);
  })
  .then(pluckedResults => {
    // pluckedResults: [[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'etc'], ...]];
    return pluckedResults;
  });
```

**Solution #2:**
It is possible to extend knex QueryBuilder to have custom functions available on all queries. So we will create `multi-pluck.js` and define a .multiPluck QueryBuilder extension for knex.

```js
/**
 * multi-pluck.js
 * We are extending knex QueryBuilder to offer multi column pluck feature
 * We add the pluck columns to the original query select statement and process result to return
 * only the values of pluck columns in the same order they are defined
 *
 * Please note that .multiPluck() needs to be last in the chain as it executes the query and breaks
 * query chaining.
 */

const QueryBuilder = require('knex/lib/query/builder');

Object.assign(QueryBuilder.prototype, {
  multiPluck: function multiPluck (...pluckColumns) {
    // add pluck columns to the query.select
    this.select(...pluckColumns);

    // run the query and map results
    return this.then(results => {

      // go over all result Objects
      return results.map(result => {

        // for each result Object, return an array of values for each pluckColumns
        return pluckColumns.map(pluckColumn => {

          // if pluck column includes table name like product.id, only use id field here
          if (pluckColumn.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            pluckColumn = pluckColumn.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
          }

          // return given column value from this result row
          return result[pluckColumn];
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And to use it, you would do something like this:

```js
// include the DB connection file which initialises knex connection
const knex = require('./db/connection').knex;

// include our multi-pluck extension
require('./db/multi-pluck');

// example function to get data from DB using the extension
async function getData () {
  return knex('product').limit(10).multiPluck('id', 'name');
}

// run the function
getData()
  .then(pluckedResults => {
    console.log(pluckedResults); // [[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'etc'], ...]
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle errors as usual
  });
```

Note that the QueryBuilder extensions could be included inside the connection initialisation file so you would have them available everywhere.

**Warning: As the multiPluck actually runs the query, it breaks the knex query chain and has to be the last function called on the query**

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was hoping there was a built-in function or configuration option I was missing; I certainly didn't expect an implemented query extension! Thanks very much for the detailed explanation -- this clears up a bunch of nagging questions -- and for multiple solutions. You rock!